# Homeomorphic product spaces [X1 x X2] X3 is homeomorphic to X1 x X2 x X3

Tags: general-topology

Show that: $[(X_1,T_1) \times (X_2, T_2)] \times (X_3,T_3) \cong (X_1,T_1) \times (X_2, T_2) \times (X_3,T_3) $.

I see that the first space is of the form $$\{((a,b),c): a,b \in X_1 \times X_2 \land c \in X_3\}$$ while the second is of the form $$\{(a,b,c): a \in X_1 \land b \in X_2 \land c \in X_3\}$$  But I'm not sure how I would create a bijective function between the two spaces besides just splitting up the first coordinate in the first set to individual coordinates in the second set.

Comment: So what's wrong with just splitting up the first coordinate?

Comment: Perhaps you mean to show $(X_1\times X_2)\times X_3$ and $X_1\times (X_2\times X_3)$ are homeomorphic?  If so, that would be an associative property for the product space topology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map you describe is the required bijection. The inverse is also clear.

Now use that a map into a product is continuous iff the composition of that map with all the projections of that product is continuous, for both of these bijections, and show they're both continuous that way.